# Blocking VPN backdoor for GEO IP blocking

Tags: geolocation, vpn

We are looking at a web project and wish to register users according to their GEO location. 
i.e. We do not want users in the UK registering as users in the USA.

Using Geo IP we can identify the user's country however a simple VPN service can negate this.

Is it possible to have a VPN IP blacklist or similar that would only force users to connect from "legitimate" IP addresses?

Comment: You can find the VPN blacklist from IP2Proxy https://www.ip2location.com/database/ip2proxy

Comment: I wouldn't be able to access such a website since I connect to the web through a VPN

Answer (score 0):

Found this:
https://www.howtogeek.com/403771/why-do-some-websites-block-vpns/

> It’s common for websites to locate and track users based on their IP
>   addresses. IP tracking is an easy way to increase account security,
>   build targeted advertisements, and show users different content
>   depending on the country in which they live. This practice of IP
>   tracking is one of the main reasons why people use VPN services, but
>   it’s also the reason why blocking VPN access to a website is so easy.